# Using CASE on a view with UNION and JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, inner-join, union

I have a query that I have been working on for a few days and none of the tutorial (w3school, ms, etc.) are helping with this particular case. I can't figure out how to make CASE work in the following:

```
SELECT T2.SlpName, T0.CardName, T0.DocNum, T0.DocType, T0.DocTotal,
CASE  T0.CANCELED WHEN 'N' THEN 
(T0.DocTotal - T0.VatSum - T0.TotalExpns) As "Total du document sans TVA",
SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100)) As "Total des commissions"
ELSE
((T0.DocTotal - T0.VatSum - T0.TotalExpns) * -1) As "Total du document sans TVA",
(SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100)) * -1) As "Total des commissions"
END
FROM OINV T0  
INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
INNER JOIN OSLP T2 ON T0.SlpCode = T2.SlpCode 
--WHERE T2.SlpName = N'[%0]' 
--AND T0.DocDate >= '[%1]' 
--AND T0.DocDate <= '[%2]'
GROUP BY T2.SlpName, T0.CardName, T0.DocNum, T0.DocType, T0.DocTotal, T0.VatSum, T0.TotalExpns, T0.CANCELED

UNION ALL

SELECT T2.SlpName, T0.CardName, T0.DocNum, T0.DocType, T0.DocTotal * -1, T0.CANCELED,
(T0.DocTotal - T0.VatSum - T0.TotalExpns) * -1 As "Total du document sans TVA",
SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100)) * -1 As "Total des commissions"
FROM ORIN T0  
INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
INNER JOIN OSLP T2 ON T0.SlpCode = T2.SlpCode 
--WHERE T2.SlpName = N'[%0]' 
--AND T0.DocDate >= '[%1]' 
--AND T0.DocDate <= '[%2]'
GROUP BY T2.SlpName, T0.CardName, T0.DocNum, T0.DocType, T0.DocTotal, T0.VatSum, T0.TotalExpns , T0.CANCELED
ORDER BY SlpName, DocNum
```

I have tried multiple variation of this query to no avail. Thank you for all and any help

Comment: The result of a `CASE` expression is one column, you can't give it different aliases

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: A case expression returns one value only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
CASE  T0.CANCELED WHEN 'N' THEN 
(T0.DocTotal - T0.VatSum - T0.TotalExpns)
ELSE
((T0.DocTotal - T0.VatSum - T0.TotalExpns) * -1) 
END As "Total du document sans TVA",
CASE  T0.CANCELED WHEN 'N' THEN 
SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100))
ELSE
(SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100)) * -1)
END As "Total des commissions"
```

`CASE` doesn't work like `if` in procedural languages, you can evaluate a condition and return a value based on that comparison.

Comment: There was my mistake, I'm used to VB/C# where one condition in case can return more then one value. Thank you for the explanation, all were good but your's pinpointed my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

`case` is an expression that returns a single value (well, that is redundant; that is what expressions do).  So, use it twice:

```
SELECT T2.SlpName, T0.CardName, T0.DocNum, T0.DocType, T0.DocTotal,
       (CASE WHEN T0.CANCELED = 'N'
             THEN (T0.DocTotal - T0.VatSum - T0.TotalExpns)
             ELSE (SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100)) * -1)
        END) As "Total du document sans TVA",
       (CASE WHEN T0.CANCELED = 'N'
             THEN SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100))
             ELSE (SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100)) * -1)
        END) As "Total des commissions"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, though I can't test it right now.

```
SELECT T2.SlpName, T0.CardName, T0.DocNum, T0.DocType, T0.DocTotal, T0.CANCELED,
CASE  T0.CANCELED WHEN 'N' THEN (T0.DocTotal - T0.VatSum - T0.TotalExpns) ELSE ((T0.DocTotal - T0.VatSum - T0.TotalExpns) * -1) END As "Total du document sans TVA",
CASE  T0.CANCELED WHEN 'N' THEN SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100)) ELSE (SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100)) * -1) END As "Total des commissions"

FROM OINV T0  
INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
INNER JOIN OSLP T2 ON T0.SlpCode = T2.SlpCode 
--WHERE T2.SlpName = N'[%0]' 
--AND T0.DocDate >= '[%1]' 
--AND T0.DocDate <= '[%2]'
GROUP BY T2.SlpName, T0.CardName, T0.DocNum, T0.DocType, T0.DocTotal, T0.VatSum, T0.TotalExpns, T0.CANCELED

UNION ALL


SELECT T2.SlpName, T0.CardName, T0.DocNum, T0.DocType, T0.DocTotal * -1 as T0.DocTotal, T0.CANCELED,
(T0.DocTotal - T0.VatSum - T0.TotalExpns) * -1 As "Total du document sans TVA",
SUM(T1.LineTotal * (T1.Commission / 100)) * -1 As "Total des commissions"
FROM ORIN T0  
INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
INNER JOIN OSLP T2 ON T0.SlpCode = T2.SlpCode 
--WHERE T2.SlpName = N'[%0]' 
--AND T0.DocDate >= '[%1]' 
--AND T0.DocDate <= '[%2]'
GROUP BY T2.SlpName, T0.CardName, T0.DocNum, T0.DocType, T0.DocTotal, T0.VatSum, T0.TotalExpns , T0.CANCELED
ORDER BY SlpName, DocNum
```